# Why isn't animation stop selector called?

Tags: iphone

I am using the following code for calling a method once my animation stops

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"swipe" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(transitionDidStop:finished:context:)];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

//My Animation

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And this is the signature of the transitionDidStop method

```
- (void)transitionDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
```

But I noticed that the method is never called even after the transition stops. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need

```
- (void)transitionDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context
```

method

But you have

```
- (void)transitionDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. I saw the MoveMe sample for the method usage and that specifies the second argument as an NSNumber. Strange. Thanks again

Comment: In apple code it works with NSNumber))
But in documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationDidStopSelector
.....

The selector should have the following method signature: animationFinished:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context.